# C++11 std::chrono::steady_clock issue on Android

Tags: android, c++, c++11

I have been using **std::chrono::steady_clock** for interval calculation in an application i am making for **Android platform.**

Code:

```
// On application start
auto timeSinceEpoch = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch();

auto timeInSec = std::chrono::duration_cast<seconds>(timeSinceEpoch).count();

log("On Enter Start Time Point - %lld", timeInSec);
```

Output:

```
On Enter Start Time Point - 521
```

**Now i switch off the phone and restart the phone. I run my application and this time Output is:**

```
On Enter Start Time Point - 114
```

As per definition at cppreference.com

"Class std::chrono::steady_clock represents a monotonic clock. **The time points of this clock cannot decrease as physical time moves forward**."

**How is the output when i restart the phone giving lesser value?**

If anyone has faced this issue please help me out here. Thanks!!

Comment: The guarantee is for a particular object of type `steady_clock` - it will never decrease its value. You are comparing two different instances of the type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So basically the epoch for steady_clock is system boot right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal requirement for a steady clock is that the result of a call to `now()` that **happens before** another call to `now()` is always less than or equal to the result of the second call. The **happens before** relationship only applies to actions within a program run. A steady clock is not required to be steady across different invocations of a program.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When i close the application and start again after say 1 hour still steadiness holds true. But only after i restart the phone the steadiness is lost. Any explanation for this?

Comment: @mechX -- "not required to" is not the same as "required not to". <g> Most likely, `now()` calls something in the OS to get the current time, and the OS clock steadily increases. When you reboot, the OS clock restarts, too.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the explanation.     This makes my work a bit tricky as i need steadiness even after reboot and i 'cannot use system_clock as it is dependent on wall clock' . Any suggestions for a possible solution or work around?

Comment: @mechX -- I'd be inclined to save the current time when the application exits, then load it in when the application restarts and use the difference between the previously-saved time and the currently-indicated time to adjust subsequent times.

Comment: Hey Pete, the issue with using system_clock is that it can be hacked by changing time from phone settings. My solution fails if the clock is not monotonic.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, AFAICT steady_clock is the same as (from Java) System.Clock.elapsedRealtime, which resets to zero on boot -- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

I'm totally failing to dig up the source code for clock_gettime, though. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/43255f3d58b03cd931d29d1ee4e5144e86e875ce/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/src/chrono.cpp#124 shows it calling clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC), but I'm not sure how to penetrate the veil from there.